# Problema con un Choice [Django - Pyhon]

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Tengo un modelo el cual tiene un campo de tipo texto  en la cual es un `choice`.

```
ANUNCIADA = 'A'
AMARRADA = 'M'
TERMINADA = 'T'
ANULADA = 'N'
LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS = (
(ANUNCIADA, 'Anunciada'),
(AMARRADA, 'Amarrada'),
(TERMINADA, 'Termina')
(ANULADA, 'Anulada'),
)

class Anuncio(models.Model):
    estado_anuncio = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Estado', choices=LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS, default='A')
```

El problema que tengo ahora es llamarlo al dato.

Pero no quiero con la iniciales, si no que digan `'A' = Anunciada`, `'M' = Amarrada`, `'T'=Terminada`, `'A'  = Anulada`. (Problema tonto el mio, ya que en primera instancia no se deseaba llamar)

Si alguien tiene una idea de como llamarla así, sería estupendo.

**PDT:**

En mi API lo llamo, pero como está , osea `'A'` , `'M'` , `'T'` ... y así no se requiere.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

A default le tienes que pasarle tu clase y el valor que quieres mostrar, y a choices también le hace falta el nombre de tu clase, suponiendo que se llama ESTADOS tu clase;
quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
class LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS(object):
  ANUNCIADA = 'A'
  AMARRADA = 'M'
  TERMINADA = 'T'
  ANULADA = 'N'

CHOICES_LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS = (
  (ANUNCIADA, 'Anunciada'),
  (AMARRADA, 'Amarrada'),
  (TERMINADA, 'Termina')
  (ANULADA, 'Anulada'),
)
class Anuncio(models.Model):
    estado_anuncio = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Estado', choices=LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS.CHOICES_LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS, default=LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS.ANUNCIADA)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero seguro ?

choices=ESTADOS.LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS, default=ESTADOS.ANUNCIADA)

Comment: seguro intentalo y me dices

Comment: Me tira este erres bro -> NameError: name 'ANUNCIADA' is not defined

Comment: Ya importaste el archivo .py en tu models?

Comment: from app.archivo-choices import *

Comment: En este archivo tengo varios modelos que tiene campos choices y funciona. El problema es que al hacer "" choices=LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS.CHOICES_LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS, default=LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS.ANUNCIADA "" No me detecta CHOICES_LIST_ESTADOS_ANUNCIOS... en este caso tu ejemplo

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, intenta de esa forma.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72610/discussion-between-jeanpierre-rivas-and-netza-l).

Answer (score 0):

esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
anuncio = Anuncio.objects.get(....)# añades los filtros que necesites
# para acceder al valor de un choice se usa get_namefield_display
# en tu caso seria get_estado_anuncio_display
print anuncio.get_estado_anuncio_display
```

puedes usarlo de la misma forma en los templates